# converting boolean values to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Im trying to standardize data stored in my database. In the sense that I want everything stored as strings. Whats the best way to convert all datatypes into strings in rails?

So if I have something like this in my database:

```
 t.funny = no #(boolean)
```

if Im converting hundreds of these to strings in a loop, whats the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Rails? Are you looking to do this in a migration?

Comment: `#to_s`. If you want to convert all columns, I would write a migration and change the column type. `change_column :users, :field, :string, limit: 100`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

monkey patches accepted? :)

here is one:

```
class Object
  def to_sb
    return 'no' if [FalseClass, NilClass].include?(self.class) 
    return 'yes' if self.class == TrueClass
    self
  end  
end  

v = true
v.to_sb
=> "yes"

v = nil
v.to_sb
=> "no"

v = false
v.to_sb
=> "no"

v = 'blah'
v.to_sb
=> "blah"
```

now in your model you can use `t.funny.to_sb`

meant to string boolean

please note that non boolean values will be returned as is

### See it in action [**here**](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=converting-boolean-values-to-string.rb&run=true)

Answer (score 3):

You could monkey-patch ActiveRecord or your database's connection adapter (e.g., `pg` gem for PostgreSQL) and have it store boolean values as strings (e.g., `Y` or `N`).

On the other hand, if you're storing everything as strings that tells me you don't care about having a typed schema. If so, perhaps you might want to take a look at alternatives such as NoSQL (MongoDB and CouchDB in particular have strong Rails integration) where everything is just a 'document' of essentially keys => values.

Answer (score 0):

false and nil are both treated as same so code can be written as

```
class Object
  def to_bool
    return 'no' unless self
    return 'yes' if self.class == TrueClass
    self
  end
end
```

Results:

```
v = true
v.to_sb
=> "yes"

v = nil
v.to_sb
=> "no"

v = false
v.to_sb
=> "no"

v = 'blah'
v.to_sb
=> "blah"
```